# Faster upload with Flask/Gunicorn

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I have containers of my app using flask + nginx + gunicorn + celery that process informations from a .xml file.

This app is inside a AWS Lightsail, which has 4g of RAM and 2vCPUs.

The files have been bigger than 400mb and takes about 40min + to upload it.

- **Does anyone knows how to make faster uploads? Would it change to increase the vcpus? (I dont believe it would)**

This is my sample code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"), strict_slashes=False)
# @login_required
async def index():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.content_length < app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']:

            file = request.files['inputfile']

            nome_xml = secure_filename(file.filename)
            if nome_xml.lower().endswith('.xml'):
                                
                exists = db.session.query(XML).filter_by(xml=nome_xml).first()
                            
                os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], exist_ok=True)
                upload_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], nome_xml)
                file.save(upload_path) **<<<< THIS IS TAKING SO LONG!**

                if not exists:
                    process_xml_file.delay(nome_xml, upload_path, 'testuser', id_evento_db)
                    
                    db.session.close_all()
                    return render_template('home/index.html')
                else:
                   
                    logger.info(f"Arquivo inválido ou já enviado anteriormente: {secure_filename(file.filename)}")
                    return render_template('home/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Dropzone library and integrate it on your upload form. You will also need to enable chunking.

Please refer to
https://codecalamity.com/uploading-large-files-by-chunking-featuring-python-flask-and-dropzone-js/

Comment: The blog @Mike mentioned has a new update with parallel upload, link to github repo: https://github.com/cdgriffith/pyfiledrop